# I can't raise a message from a PostgreSQL function in a Spring Boot application

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, logback

I am developing a Spring Boot application with the PostgreSQL database. I have made a PostgreSQL function which contains the following code:

```
raise info 'my message';
```

In my application I have a logback.xml file containing the following line:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="INFO" />
```

Why can't I see my message on the Eclipse console?

P.S. If I replace `raise info 'my message';` with `raise 'my message'` I can see the message but afterwards the application terminates because it raises an exception...

In my `Foo` class I have st like this

```
@Query(value="select * from myFunction()", nativeQuery=true)
List<Thing> myFunction();
```

And in another class I do this:

```
List<Thing> things=foo.myFunction()
```

Comment: Messages "printed" using `raise info` are returned to the client as a `java.sql.SQLWarning` on the  `java.sql.Statement` object. Your application needs to actively retrieve them from there using  `Statement.getWarnings()` after a SQL statement has finished

Comment: I don't have a Connection object.

Comment: I have st like this: @Query(value="select * from myFunction()", nativeQuery=true)
List<Thing> myFunction();